# can i change the value of a property from another domain class? - grails

Tags: grails, composite-key, grails-domain-class

I'm a newbie in grails. i'm having a problem right now in my domain classes. I have 3 domain classes, class **Patient**,class **Nurse** and class **NursePatient**, the class **NursePatient** is a composite key where you can see who is the attending Nurse in a Patient, so if you view its table you can only see the id's of nurses and patients. This is my code for  **Nurse** class:

```
class Nurse {

String name
Nurse partner
boolean idle = true

static belongsTo = [hospital: Hospital]

static constraints = {

    name(blank:false)
    partner(nullable:true)
    hospital(nullable:false)

}

String toString(){

    "Nurse ${name}"

}


}
```

--> and this is my domain class for **NursePatient**:

```
class NursePatient implements Serializable{


Nurse nurse
Patient patient

static mapping = {

    version false
    id composite:['nurse', 'patient']
}

static constraints = {
    patient(nullable:false, validator:{val, obj -> val.hospital == obj.nurse.hospital})
    nurse(nullable:false)
}

String toString(){

    "Nurse ${nurse.name} - ${patient.name}"

}

void saveIt(Nurse x, Patient y){

    def np = new NursePatient(nurse: x, patient: y)

    if(np.save()){

       def n = nurse.get(nurse.id)
       n.idle = false

    }


}

}
```

--> I was asked to print a list of nurses who doesn't have a patient. I was thinking that the moment I save in table using the **saveIt()** method from class **NursePatient**, once the **save()** is successful it changes the value of the property idle of class **Nurse** from **true** to **false** so that querying is much more easier. My problem is I don't if my code in class **NursePatient** is correct or is it possible to change the value of a property from another class. Please Help me.. thank You!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing properties of domain classes inside different classes is fine.

However, you don't really need a `NursePatient` class. If you declare the relationship between Nurses and Patients as many-to-many, like this:

```
class Nurse {
    static hasMany = [patients: Patient]
    ...
}

class Patient {
    static hasMany = [nurses: Nurse]
    ...
}
```

then Grails will create and update the needed join table automatically. You can then query for all the nurses without patients using [Criteria API](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#criteria):

```
def nursesWithoutPatients = Nurse.withCriteria { isEmpty("patients") }
```